# A way to say custom but not minhag

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, language

Within the context of Judaism *Minhag* is a term of art that is usually translated in English as "custom". There are times when I want to ask a question on MiYodea about the [customs](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/custom?s=t) of Jews which are not necessarily minhag. (In this case I use the English definition of the word and not it's Hebrew counterpart). However I know that if I do, some people will translate custom in their minds as minhag and correctly point out that the situation I've posed is not an actual Jewish minhag, which will likely lead to a long and convoluted discussion in the comments about word choice and intentions. I'd obviously like to avoid that if I can - is there a better way to phrase it?

For example, consider the following question:

- Where did the custom of saying "l'chaim" when drinking alcohol come from?

Substituting in 'habitual practice' (suggested by dictionary.com) for custom seems awkward. What's a better way to word this question so it doesn't cause confusion? Habit? Practice? Concept? Idea?

In case anyone is worried, no, I have no intention of asking that question, it's just a sample. But the answer is [here](http://forward.com/articles/146279/lchaim-a-bad-grammatical-error/) if you're curious.

Comment: You've tagged this [meta-tag:asking-questions], but the question seems as relevant to answers as to questions.

Answer (score 8):

[I](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6970) [like](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8102) [*practice*](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15703).

Comment: or in Hebrew "hanhaga"